# no select filtering product for lower or higher price PHP MYSQL Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form that contains a `select` tag, to be able to filter by greater or lesser price, when I select an option if the filtering, the problem is that the selection never changes of option always remains in the first option, I think it has to do something with The Selected attribute = "selected", I have tried it in the following way but it has not worked for me. and I have even tried to put .atrr ('selected', true) from JQuery, but when I try this I do not respect the $ statement ("# search_form"). submit (); Another thing for the front use materializecss

-------------------HTML-----------------

```
          <form method="get" id="search_form"><!--Formulario para filtros-->

          <select name="prices" id="price">
          <option value="ASC"<?php
          if (isset($_POST['prices'])
           && $_POST['prices'] == 'ASC') {
          $selected = ' selected="selected"';
          }
           ?> <?php $selected?>>ASC</option>

          <option value="DESC"<?php
          if (isset($_POST['prices'])
           && $_POST['prices'] == 'DESC') {
         $selected = ' selected="selected"';
          }
          ?> <?php $selected?>>DESC</option>

          </select>

           <label>Ordena Por:</label>
```

--------------------JQuery----------------------------------

```
         $('select#price').change(function(){

          $("#search_form").submit();
           return false;  



           });
```

------------------PHP----------------------------------------

```
          if(isset($_GET['prices']) && $_GET['prices']!="") :

           if($_GET['prices']=='ASC'):

           $sql .= " ORDER BY precio ASC";   


           elseif($_GET['prices']=='DESC'):

           $sql .=" ORDER BY precio DESC";


            endif;   

           endif;
```

Comment: Estas en StackOverflow en ingles.  Puedes hacer tu pregunta en espanol aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You should post this on [Stackoverflow Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (Deberías postear esto en Stackoverflow en Español)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is written in Spanish language.

Comment: sorry, I already asked the question correctly

Comment: You don't seem to actually be echoing out the $selected variable you make... `<?php $selected?>` should be `<?php echo $selected;?>`. I'm sure theres other issues, but this code is difficult to follow as its so piecemeal.

Comment: Thanks @IncredibleHat to this perfectly worked, I am a beginner in this and I have recommended that all my HTML code keep it in a variable, so have a cleaner code